# Error: storage size of 'c' isn't known

Tags: c, struct, adt

I'm getting "Error: storage size of 'c' isn't known" when i try to create the variable "c" of my struct called "struct car"

Here is the code:

*teste.h*

```
#ifndef TESTE_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTE_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct car Car;

#endif // TESTE_H_INCLUDED
```

*teste.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "teste.h"

struct car{
    char name[20];
    char model[20];

};
```

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "teste.h"
int main()
{
    Car c;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error... I bet it is something stupid... could someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Car structure on the header file is just a forward declaration, when it's included on main.c, it only has knowledge of the forward declaration but no clue of how it's defined (or in this case, what the size of the struct is). define your struct on the header file.

```
struct car {
    char name[20];
    char model[20];
};
```

Comment: Probably the struct is not intended to be used by direct access to the struct fields, but instead via accessor functions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Simple, yet so helpful. Saved me some hours of my life!

Comment: @Felipe Romero, you saved me so much frustration. Why is that adding the definition (as a difference to just the declaration) to the headers makes the difference?